# I need to print what is directly after a matched string

Tags: python, api, awk

I'm building a slack robot for me and my friends and in that process I'm using the uptimerobot and slack API. My problem is that I'm unable to figure out how to print out only certain values from a return message of the uptimerobot API. This is how the code looks like right now:

```
import requests
#from subprocess import call


#UPTIMEROBOT
url = "https://api.uptimerobot.com/v2/getMonitors"

payload = "api_key=apikeyhere&format=json&all_time_uptime_ratio=1"
headers = {
    'content-type': "application/x-www-form-urlencoded",
    'cache-control': "no-cache"
    }

response = requests.request("POST", url, data=payload, headers=headers)
```

If I run the script I get the following as output (some is omitted):

```
{"stat":"ok","pagination":{"offset":0,"limit":50,"total":3},"monitors":[{"id":value,"friendly_name":"name"
```

What I'm doing right now is simply running the script and piping into awk like this:

```
python3 slackbot.py | awk -F "friendly_name:" {'print $2'}
```

But it doesn't return anything at all. What i want to get is only "name" without the quotes around it.

If someone would help me out it'd be great.

Comment: I recommend taking a look at jq: https://stedolan.github.io/jq/ ... it'll parse/slice/filter JSON on your command line. That said, it's probably best to actually parse the JSON response from within your py program instead of parsing stdout

Comment: `response.json['monitors'][0]['friendly_name']`

Comment: @wilkesybear I think so too that it would be wise to parse the json response directly in the script and get what i want like that. I'm new to this and i have no clue how to move forward. Do you know?

Comment: @jordanm Thanks for the reply, however i don't know what to make of it. Should i add that to my script?

Comment: @nillenilsson yes

Comment: @jordanm I'm sorry i dont get how i can use it. Can you explain please?

Comment: Sorry, it should be `reponse.json()['monitors'][0]['friendly_name']`. The `json()` method on a requests response object returns the parsed json as a dict. The rest just accesses the element you are looking for.

Comment: @jordanm Ah that worked perfectly! Thank you! Now all i have left is to put it in a loop :)

Answer (score 1):

`Awk` probably isn't the best solution to this as you can more easily manipulate json data by treating it as an object. Using the command line program [jq](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/) would work well, with something like `jq '.monitors[0].friendly_name'`.

Working example using a json object based on your question:

```
echo '{"stat":"ok","pagination":{"offset":0,"limit":50,"total":3},"monitors":[{"id":1,"friendly_name":"name"'}]} | jq '.monitors[0].friendly_name'
```

The reason your awk command didn't work is because you are splitting the data by `friendly_name:` when you want `friendly_name":"`.

If you want to add the `":"` you'd need to escape the double quotes like this:

```
awk -F "friendly_name\":\"" {'print $2'}
```

That would still leave you with an extra `"` on the end. You could remove the `"` fairly easily but I'd recommend going the jq route as it will be more easily maintainable.